# Speeding up rails development deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I got a rails app that requires redis, mongod, and postgres before starting with `rails s`. I do not like open several tabs on my terminal and open these services one by one. Is there a way to run everything with one command/script? Is there a specific gem that might help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Look into using the foreman gem. It should do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is mentioned by @Tres with using the [foreman gem](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html). If you are using [rvm](https://rvm.io/) you can use a [.rvmrc](https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/) file in your project. There you can simply define some shell commands like

```
mongod --port 23017
postgresql start
```

and the like ...